# How to (only!) use the own build script in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, compilation

How can I use my own build script in MS Visual Studio and nothing else (linked to F7)?

I have added my script as pre build step and it works fine, but afterwards visual studio always tries to run its own compilation (which fails). How can I prevent VS from doing this?

Comment: Either exclude everything from compilation - right click on the files, or just run your script from a prompt and use VS as an editor.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, but the 1st is not what I was aiming for and the 2nd is still throwing some linker error (LINK : fatal error LNK1123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "utility" project type. Currently the linker is trying to create an EXE, DLL or LIB, depending on your project type. But those 3 types all require object files, and a "utlitity" project does not.

Comment: Thank you! For me it did the project type "Makefile project".